# Suppose that $x=3-4t$ and $y=5+2t$. Find $x$ in terms of $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So i have the following equations:

$x=3-4t$,

$y=5+2t$

I'm slightly puzzled by this. The question asks to find $x$ in terms of $y$, but the above equations have also $t$ included. This to me signals that I need to preprocess the equations such that the $t$ variable is cancelled out entirely. This can ofcourse be easily done with elimination. However, that would result in a single equation with two unknow variables $x$ and $y$ which would be impossible to evaluate as it would just give me an expression. What should I do in this case?

Comment: That's what x "in terms of y" means. A single equation with x and y, where you have x = something with y in it. You just have x on one side of the equals, and the rest on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add equation $(1)$ with two times equation $(2)$, you get
$$2y+x = 13$$

Answer (score 2):

By equation 2$$y=5+2t\\
t=\frac{y-5}{2}\\
$$
substitute this equation into equation 1
$$
x=3-4\frac{y-5}{2}\\
x=13-2y
$$

Finally we get $x=13-2y$

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation, $t=(y-5)/2.$ Now substitute this expression for $t$ in the first equation.